# jQuery and active menu items - what is the best?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a menu and I would like to add class="selected" to the active menu items. I have issues with `location.pathname` when the URL is like:
- http://www.google.com/sub-folder/adrov48.php

So it basicaly works only when url is simple like that:
- http://www.google.com/adrov50.php

I know there is lot of similair questions, but If you take a look at the code below I'm using a "new" method, but it's not really working, that's where you guys jump in :)

Javascript code:

```
            var path = location.pathname;

            $("a[href='" + [path] + "']").parents("li").each(function() {   
                    $(this).addClass("selected");
            });
```

Any ideas how can I make this work, possible with jQuery.

If anyone thinks that my method is bad or not ideal, please tell me why and post or link me your solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you do something like this:

```
// Check complete URL
var path = location.href;
$("#navID li a").each(function() {
    // Check if there is a match between the URL and the navigation link    
    if(path.match($(this).attr("href")) $(this).parent().addClass("selected");
});
```

Comment: Because in my hrefs i don't have full URL :S                    
Basicaly => href="http://www.google.com/sub-folder/adrov48.php" can't match href="adrov48.php"...

Comment: You're actually matching "adrov48.php" to "google.com/sub-folder/adrov48.php" here..

Comment: It's working here: http://jsfiddle.net/kayen/mCtFE/ ; I've added comments to why it was not working on your fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for effort, everything works, but one question remains, which is what if URL is `http://google.com/sub-folder/adrov48/announcements.php?id=204` ... Fiddle here => http://jsfiddle.net/mCtFE/6/

Answer (score 1):

combine location.pathname and location.search to create URL fragment